# How do i properly refer to the indexes within $_FILES?

Tags: php, arrays, image, upload

I have the following code:

```
   foreach($_FILES['add_prod_image'] as &$image){ 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($image["name"]); 
$uploadOk = 1; 
$imageFileType
    = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   /home/matthew/www/cart/admin/process.php on line 30

However when I `var_dump( $_FILES['add_prod_image']['name']);`

I get:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> string(16) "plate with 5.jpg"
}
```

I'm trying to test with just one image,

The output is correct, the name, tmp_name and everything else I need is there but as soon as I try to store it in a variable (E.G. `$image = $_FILES['add_prod_image']`), I start getting the index errors...

Any ideas?

Comment: name != tmp_name. are you sure this is the right code ?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, sorry, the error I copied is one of many. I'll edit it to reflect the situation more accurately.

Comment: To understand its outer structure, `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: ['add_prod_image'] is an array it contains a key-variable pair of `name = foo` but also others, so as you loop each only one key pair will match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the index as designated as $index in my example code:

This assumes your HTML in my snippet is similar to yours.

This applies to inputs that have the multiple

```
foreach ($_FILES["add_prod_image"]["name"] as $index=> $image) {
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($image["name"][$index]);
}
```

The "proper" way to retrieve multiple images would be:

```
foreach ($_FILES["add_prod_image"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["add_prod_image"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["add_prod_image"]["name"][$key]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file);
  }
}

array (
  'add_prod_image' => 
  array (
    'name' => 
    array (
      0 => 'image1.jpg',
      1 => 'image2gif',
      2 => 'image3.gif',
    ),
    'type' => 
    array (
      0 => 'image/jpeg',
      1 => 'image/gif',
      2 => 'image/gif',
    ),
    'tmp_name' => 
    array (
      0 => '/tmp/phpS3tMZx',
      1 => '/tmp/php31MQBf',
      2 => '/tmp/phpyHuUdX',
    ),
    'error' => 
    array (
      0 => 0,
      1 => 0,
      2 => 0,
    ),
    'size' => 
    array (
      0 => 535,
      1 => 506,
      2 => 507,
    ),
  ),
)
$['add_prod_image']['name'][$index]
$['add_prod_image']['type'][$index]
$['add_prod_image']['tmp_name'][$index]
$['add_prod_image']['size'][$index]
```

### An HTML5 DOC Type is Required.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Test Bed</title></head></body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="add_prod_image" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

It may work without an HTML5 Doc Type in some Browsers.  multiple is an HTML5 feature and requires an HTML5 Doc Type.  Browsers will generally fix errors but is better not to have errors.  If you use HTML5 features, use a HTML5 doc Type.

`foreach($array as $value){}` is used when the index (key) is of no use.  When you want to use the index (key) value then use: 
`foreach($array as $key => $value){}` .  The `=>` is PHP array syntax for `key => value`.

Comment: Ok I understand that. I guess it's my fault, I shamelessly copied the code for image uploading and never thought to scrutinize it. I'll try that solution out and get back to you.

Comment: So i tried it. I changed it to this:
foreach($_FILES['add_prod_image']['error'] as $key=> $error){
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['add_prod_image']['name']);

But now I get: Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I understand now! So the 'name' variables are stored in the 'name' sub-array (if you will), with index 0 through 5. As i understand it, $_FILES[add_prod_image'] is an array, containing an array called 'name', containing 5 indexes containing the name of each file respectively.

Comment: code looks correct, I will test.  One minute please.

Comment: It works. Thank you! The file uploaded perfectly. The only thing I don't understand is this: If we are using $_FILES['add_prod_image']['name'] as our index, how then is the script able to retrieve other variables such as $_FILES['add_prod_image']['tmp_name'], or ...['size']??? are we not locked into the ['name'] array within the $_FILES array?

Comment: Yeah, I tried multiple files and it doesn't work. I'm totally lost. I'll read up and get back.

Comment: I got it to work by adding an HTML5 DOC Type. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">`  See Update.  If you need more help, leave another comment.  I have it working.  Remember to change the code once the HTML multiple is working.

Comment: Hey! I have it working WITHOUT the doctype. I was just windering if you could point me to a tutorial, or explain this to me. What does the "=>" symbol do in the following expression: foreach($_FILES['add_prod_image']['name'] as $index=> $image) Is it like a pointer in C++? Thanks.